# SLD applying not working in openlayers

Tags: geoserver, javascript, openlayers-2

My sld is not applying

```
function cusMap(strSld_body,talukaName,name){
console.log(strSld_body);
var query = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS.Post(name,
        geoServerURL, {
            LAYERS : 'VP:village_customize',
            sld_body : strSld_body,
            format : 'image/jpeg',
            transparent : 'true'
        },
        {
            unsupportedBrowsers: [],
            isBaseLayer: false,
            yx : {'EPSG:4326' : true}
        } );
      query.mergeNewParams({'CQL_FILTER': "Taluka='"+talukaName+"'"});
      query.mergeNewParams({'sld_body': strSld_body});
      query=registerEvents(query);
map.addLayer(query);

}
```

The sld I am applying is as below

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.1.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se">
  <NamedLayer><se:Name>Village</se:Name><UserStyle><se:Name>Village</se:Name><se:FeatureTypeStyle><se:Rule><se:Name>5 - 121</se:Name><se:Description><se:Title>5 - 121</se:Title></se:Description><ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"><ogc:Or><ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>Village</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>Satsan</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>Village</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>Arkhi</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>Village</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>Vadvas</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>Village</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>Lakhanasar</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>Village</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>Mahudi Moti</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>Village</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>Mahudi Nani</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>Village</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>Rampura Mahudi</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>Village</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>Kotda (Jegol)</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>Village</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>Rajkot</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>Village</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>Bhilachal</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>Village</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>Vavdhara</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>Village</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>Hariyawada</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>Village</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>Jegol</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>Village</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>Atal</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>Village</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>Bhakodar</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>Village</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>Dhaneri</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>Village</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>Velavas</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>Village</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>Malpuriya</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>Village</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>Ranol</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>Village</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>Chodungri</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>Village</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>Bhadli Kotha</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>Village</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>Nandotra (Brahmanvas</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>Village</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>Jorapura (Lodpa)</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>Village</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>Nilpur</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>Village</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>Nandotra (Thakorvas)</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>Village</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>Sikariya</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>Village</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>Bhakhar Moti</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>Village</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>Lodpa</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>Village</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>Ramsida (Chhapra)</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo></ogc:Or></ogc:Filter><se:PolygonSymbolizer><se:Fill><se:SvgParameter name="fill">#ccffcc</se:SvgParameter></se:Fill><se:Stroke><se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter><se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.26</se:SvgParameter><se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter></se:Stroke></se:PolygonSymbolizer></se:Rule><se:Rule><se:Name>122 - 238</se:Name><se:Description><se:Title>122 - 238</se:Title></se:Description><ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"><ogc:Or><ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>Village</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>Vagor</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>Village</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>Zat</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>Village</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>Bhandotra</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>Village</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>Dantiwada</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>Village</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>Akoli</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>Village</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>Ganguwada</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>Village</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>Bhadali (Zat)</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>Village</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>Gangudara</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>Village</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>Deri</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>Village</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>Odhava</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>Village</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>Shergadh Odhava</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>Village</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>Ratanpur</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>Village</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>Godh</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>Village</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>Bhakhar Nani</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>Village</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>Vaghrol</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>Village</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>Dangiya</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo></ogc:Or></ogc:Filter><se:PolygonSymbolizer><se:Fill><se:SvgParameter name="fill">#b3ffb3</se:SvgParameter></se:Fill><se:Stroke><se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter><se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.26</se:SvgParameter><se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter></se:Stroke></se:PolygonSymbolizer></se:Rule><se:Rule><se:Name>239 - 355</se:Name><se:Description><se:Title>239 - 355</se:Title></se:Description><ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"><ogc:Or><ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>Village</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>Dhaniyawada</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>Village</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>Gundari</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo></ogc:Or></ogc:Filter><se:PolygonSymbolizer><se:Fill><se:SvgParameter name="fill">#99ff99</se:SvgParameter></se:Fill><se:Stroke><se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter><se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.26</se:SvgParameter><se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter></se:Stroke></se:PolygonSymbolizer></se:Rule><se:Rule><se:Name>356 - 472</se:Name><se:Description><se:Title>356 - 472</se:Title></se:Description><ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"><ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>Village</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>Bhilada</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo></ogc:Filter><se:PolygonSymbolizer><se:Fill><se:SvgParameter name="fill">#66ff66</se:SvgParameter></se:Fill><se:Stroke><se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter><se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.26</se:SvgParameter><se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter></se:Stroke></se:PolygonSymbolizer></se:Rule><se:Rule><se:Name>473 - 589</se:Name><se:Description><se:Title>473 - 589</se:Title></se:Description><se:PolygonSymbolizer><se:Fill><se:SvgParameter name="fill">#33ff33</se:SvgParameter></se:Fill><se:Stroke><se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter><se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.26</se:SvgParameter><se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter></se:Stroke></se:PolygonSymbolizer></se:Rule><se:Rule><se:Name>590 - 706</se:Name><se:Description><se:Title>590 - 706</se:Title></se:Description><se:PolygonSymbolizer><se:Fill><se:SvgParameter name="fill">#00ff00</se:SvgParameter></se:Fill><se:Stroke><se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter><se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.26</se:SvgParameter><se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter></se:Stroke></se:PolygonSymbolizer></se:Rule><se:Rule><se:Name>707 - 823</se:Name><se:Description><se:Title>707 - 823</se:Title></se:Description><ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"><ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>Village</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>Panthawada</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo></ogc:Filter><se:PolygonSymbolizer><se:Fill><se:SvgParameter name="fill">#00cc00</se:SvgParameter></se:Fill><se:Stroke><se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter><se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.26</se:SvgParameter><se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter></se:Stroke></se:PolygonSymbolizer></se:Rule></se:FeatureTypeStyle></UserStyle></NamedLayer></StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

The sld is not showing any error in geoserver but layer is not taking passed sld to render.

The sld is applying which is default in geoserver not that one which I am passing. Can anyone help me to get out of this?

Comment: Try making the name in the layer query match the `NamedLayer` in the SLD. That is, replace `<se:Name>Village</se:Name>` with `<se:Name>VP:village_customize</se:Name>`

Comment: But Legend is not coming in Ext JS. How can i force to show legend?

Comment: I think that is a completely separate question.

Comment: Here is link to new question http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/174237/how-to-force-ext-js-to-show-legends-with-open-layers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is, replace

`<se:Name>Village</se:Name>` with `<se:Name>VP:village_customize</se:Name>` in SLD.