# How to force EXT JS - GeoEXT to show legends with OpenLayers?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-2, geoext, ext-js

My sld is applying as below

```
  function cusMap(strSld_body,talukaName,name){
       console.log(strSld_body);
    var query = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS.Post(name,  
    geoServerURL, {
        LAYERS : 'VP:village_customize',
        sld_body : strSld_body,
        format : 'image/jpeg',
        transparent : 'true'
    },
    {
        unsupportedBrowsers: [],
        isBaseLayer: false,
        yx : {'EPSG:4326' : true}
    } );
  query.mergeNewParams({'CQL_FILTER': "Taluka='"+talukaName+"'"});
  query.mergeNewParams({'sld_body': strSld_body});
  query=registerEvents(query);
   map.addLayer(query);

 }
```

But the legend is not coming as per sld made. How can I force legends to show up?

I am using Ext JS Tree to show legends.

```
 Ext.onReady(function() {

var mapPanel = new GeoExt.MapPanel({
    renderTo : 'mymap',
    width:780,
    zoom:7,
    region: "center",
    //autoWidth:true,
    boxMaxWidth : 762,
    boxMaxHeight : 490,
    map: map
    //layout: "fit"       

});

var tree = new Ext.tree.TreePanel({
    renderTo : 'mytree',
    region: "east",
    title: "Layers / Legends",

    width: 230,
    boxMaxHeight : 455,

    autoScroll: true,
    enableDD: true,
    collapsible: false,
    split: false,

    plugins: [{
            ptype: "gx_treenodecomponent"
        }],
    loader: {
        applyLoader: true,
        uiProviders: {
            "custom_ui": LayerNodeUI
        }
    },
    root: {
        nodeType: "gx_layercontainer",
        loader: {
            baseAttrs: {
                uiProvider: "custom_ui"

            },
            createNode: function(attr) {
                // add a WMS legend to each node created
                attr.component = {
                    xtype: "gx_wmslegend",
                    layerRecord: mapPanel.layers.getByLayer(attr.layer),
                    showTitle: false,
                    cls: "legend"
                }
                return GeoExt.tree.LayerLoader.prototype.createNode.call(this, attr);
            }
        }
    },
    rootVisible: false,
    lines: true
});

new Ext.Viewport({
    layout: 'border',
    region: 'center',
    autoScroll: true,

    split: false,
    renderTo : 'bodypanel',
            items: [
                  mapPanel,tree

            ]


});

});
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to submit an http request using the wms service and a GetLegendGraphic request. Details [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/get_legend_graphic/legendgraphic.html). Pass your sld as a SLD_BODY parameter to the request

This should return the image and then you have to replace the one you allready have (I pressume you get the default style you attached to the Geoserver layer) with the one returned on the response.

Comment: But how to update legend tree which is in ExtJS-tree-legend?

Comment: this is up to you. You dont provide any code about extjs so I dont really know how you do it.  I guess you have a method to populate the tree with the images. Is it right? If yes use a new method to update some of them.

Comment: I have used javascript as shown in edited question.

Comment: Amigo, this is Geoext it is not pure extjs+ol2. You better mention it within your question as what you ask is specific for Geoext. I could help you out if it was pure extjs+ol2 but I am not familiar with Geoext

Comment: Oh.. Thank you very much for your kind support. You helped me a lot. Thank You. I will find some other way of GeoEXT.